# Efficient way to store HTML in database

Tags: sql, database, db2, compression

I have a text editor on webpage. It contains function like Bold, Italics, Highlight. So a text may contain any of these. It may even contain numbered or unnumbered lists.
The text editor generates HTML for the formatted text.

Due to this, the format text data (html) is atleast 60% more than what unformatted text would have been.

This consumes lot of space (in terms of characters) which leads to space hungry database.

Is there a way to compress or some other way to store this efficiently ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in compression function in Db2. But you may write your own external functions (using Java or C/C++) to implement such a functionality. I can provide a java example (using [java.util.zip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/zip/package-summary.html) package) of such an implementation, if you are interesting.
Another way is to use Db2 [Row compression](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0060027.html). Db2 may compress any non-LOB columns and so called "inlined" LOBs.
[Storing LOBs inline in table rows](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0054525.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you store your data as XML in a Db2 `XML` data-type column, it will be stored in a more efficient form than raw text

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/c0022770.html